# Import .mdf file using sql server 2016 import export wizard

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to sql. I have a .mdf file & I have sql server 2016. Can you please help me import the .mdf file using sql server 2016 & view the .mdf file content?

I want to view the data of .mdf file

Answer (score 0):

If your `mdf` file is a database's data file (what the file extension implies), Import-Export Wizard will not understand it.

Instead, you should attach this file as a database. For exact syntax, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016&tabs=sqlpool), specifically you'll be interested in the `attach_rebuild_log` option.